# Customize swagger annotation in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I am happy with using swagger to generate API documentation for the front-end developer.

But if I have some methods that need to have a Bearer token or something else in the header of the requests. Problem comes out that I have to repeatedly Copy&Paste the whole annotation on each method. It violates DRY principal and when I have to make some changes on the Bearer token documentation, it will be a disaster.

Current

```
@ApiImplicitParam(name="Authorization",value = "Bearer token",dataType = "string", paramType ="header")
public ResponseEntity<Void> doSth(){};

@ApiImplicitParam(name="Authorization",value = "Bearer token",dataType = "string", paramType ="header")
public ResponseEntity<Void> doSth2(){};

@ApiImplicitParam(name="Authorization",value = "Bearer token",dataType = "string", paramType ="header")
public ResponseEntity<Void> doSth3(){};
```

What I want to do is create an annotation **@ApiOauth2** which is inherited from
**@ApiImplicitParam(name="Authorization",value = "Bearer token",dataType = "string", paramType ="header")** and can be identified by swagger

```
@ApiOauth2
public ResponseEntity<Void> doSth(){};

@ApiOauth2
public ResponseEntity<Void> doSth2(){};

@ApiOauth2
public ResponseEntity<Void> doSth3(){};
```

I searched that annotation can not be extended, how can I achieve such approach?

Comment: What library are you using? Are you using springfox?

Comment: @DilipKrishnan thanks for your reply. Yes, 1.0.2 version. It's old name is swagger-springmvc

Comment: Its a lot simpler to do with the [2.0 version](https://github.com/springfox/springfox) Its still in snapshot status, but we plan on releasing shortly. We're still working on the documentation but someone will be available at the [gitter](https://gitter.im/springfox/springfox) chat room to help out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 @ApiImplicitParams({
 @ApiImplicitParam(
     name="Authorization",
     value = "Bearer token",
     dataType = "string", 
     paramType ="header")
})
public @interface ApiOauth2 {

}
```